# Getting error: The expression is not callable Mongoose NextJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, next.js

I trying to save data to a mongoose model on NextJS page. I get a typescript error on this line:

```
await User.create(data)
```

> This expression is not callable.
> Each member of the union type '{ <Z = Document |
> _AllowStringsForIds<Pick<Pick<_LeanDocument<Document>, "_id" | "__v" | "id">, "_id" | "__v" | "id">>>(doc: Z): Promise<...>; <Z =
> Document<...> | _AllowStringsForIds<...>>(docs: Z[], options?:
> SaveOptions): Promise<...>; <Z = Document<...> |
> _AllowStringsForIds<...>>(...docs: Z[]): Promis...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

The code works - I can see the data added into the database, but

1. Deploy on heroku fails with the same error
2. I want to clear this error on my VSCode [Problems] tab as well (anoying)

Here is what I export from my User model:

```
export default  (mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema));
```

Comment: Strangely This way:

       `var user = new User(data)`
                `await user.save()`
Works- No errors, successfully builds on Heroku as well. But WHY the first approach isnt working?

Comment: Same problem here, but using `findOneAndUpdate()` or `findByIdAndUpdate()`. Not sure if it's a Type declaration issue in Mongoose package. That's a very strange behaviour.

Comment: @MauricioContreras

Instead of directly calling `User.create(...)`, I used `let riko = new User(...)` and then `riko.save()` which fixed the problem for me. But I still dont understand why this error appeared in the first place.

I hope this would work for you as well

Comment: Actually I'm using: `//@ts-ignore` and it works for me. But I would like to know if this is a bug or what. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. :(

Answer (score 13):

Even though a little older, leaving my insights here:

I had the same issue and found I could make it work without `@ts-ignore` by explicitly giving the `mongoose.models.User` the same type as used with the schema.

```
export interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

const schema = new mongoose.Schema<User>(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  }
);
    
export default (mongoose.models.User as mongoose.Model<User>) || mongoose.model('User', schema);
```